# kotlin) It turns off when the app turns on : The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly

Tags: android, kotlin, admob

I'm using android studio (version giraffe), and this problem happened.
Both build.gradle and manifest have been modified but have occurred.

**java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException**

manifest.xml

`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MultiNews"
    tools:targetApi="33">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.ca-app-pub-4573819979732972~4126009890"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>



    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

`

settings.gradle
build.gradle
[image]